# Euler 3 Python. Putting the prime numbers into a list

Tags: python, math, primes, prime-factoring

Im still pretty new to python and I'm trying to get all of the prime numbers from 600851475143 into a list. However, I keep getting a random assortment of numbers in the list instead of the prime numbers. I'm not really sure where I am going wrong. Thank you for your time

```
import math
factors_list = []
prime_factors = []

def number_factors(s):
    s = int(math.sqrt(s))
    for num in range(2, s):
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                factors_list.append(num)
            else:
                prime_factors.append(num)

number_factors(600851475143)

print factors_list
print prime_factors
```

Comment: There are major problems with this algorithm. Suggestion: Add a few print statements to your loops to see what numbers your algorithm is producing. Don't try to process that huge number until you're certain that your code works properly on small numbers that you can check by hand. On a related note, you may find it helpful to follow your algorithm using pencil & paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you append to `prime_factor` every time `if (num % i) == 0`.  So, for example, if `num=12` (not prime), and `i=5` you'll do the append to `prime_factor`.

Instead, you should only append if it has **no** divisors at all, not just a single number doesn't divide evenly.

I'll warn you ahead of time though, this problem is not only about calculating prime numbers, but that 600851475143 is a very large number.  So you should probably get your current code working as a learning exercise, but you'll need to rethink your approach to the full solution.

Comment: What would be a way to the best way to deal with very large numbers? So far I have only learned about range and xrange in my class

Comment: In general, I think it's against the goal of Euler problems to help with the solution.  I helped here because it was a programming problem unrelated to the core of the question.  At least try it on your own for awhile before asking for help with the next step.  Euler problems are meant to be hard.

Comment: 600851475143 isn't _that_ huge: its largest prime factor must be less than a million, and in fact is under 7000. True, it'd be a problem in a language limited to 32 bit integers, but it's a breeze to factorize in Python even with a fairly simple algorithm.

Comment: I think we agree that the OP's basic solution is currently doing a lot of work that's not solving the desired problem. Since it's a Project Euler problem, I'd rather not explicitly mention what that code _is_ actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better algorithm for factoring *n*. I'll describe it in words, so you can work out the coding yourself.

```
1) Set f = 2. Variable f represents the current trial factor.
2) If f * f > n, then n must be prime, so output n and stop.
3) Divide n by f. If the remainder is 0, then f is a factor of n,
     so output f and set n = n / f, then return to Step 2.
4) Since the remainder in the prior step was not 0, set f = f + 1
     and return to Step 2.
```

For instance, to factor 13195, first set *f* = 2; the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, the remainder in Step 3 is 1, so in Step 4 set *f* = 3 and return to Step 2. Now the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, the remainder in Step 3 is 1, so in Step 4 set *f* = 4 and return to Step 2. Now the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, the remainder in Step 3 is 3, so in Step 4 set *f* = 5 and return to Step 2.

Now the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, but the remainder in Step 3 is 0, so 5 is a factor of 13195; output 5, set *n* = 2639, and return to Step 2. Now the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, the remainder in Step 3 is 4, so in Step 4 set *f* = 6 and return to Step 2. Now the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, the remainder in Step 3 is 5, so in Step 4 set *f* = 7 and return to Step 2.

Now the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, but the remainder in Step 3 is 0, so 7 is a factor of 2639 (and also of 13195); output 7, set *n* = 377, and return to Step 2. Now the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, the remainder in Step 3 is 6, so in Step 4 set *f* = 8 and return to Step 2. Continue in this way until *f* = 13.

Now the test in Step 2 is not satisfied, but the remainder in Step 3 is 0, so 13 is a factor of 377 (and also of 2639 and 13195); output 13, set *n* = 29, and return to Step 2. Here the test in Step 2 *is* satisfied, since 13 * 13 = 169 which is greater than 29, so 29 is prime, output it and halt. The final factorization is 5 * 7 * 13 * 29 = 13195.

The factorization of 600851475143 works in exactly the same way, except that it takes longer. There are better ways to factor integers. But this algorithm is simple, and is sufficient for PE3.

Answer (score 0):

This will run quite slowly for large numbers. Consider the case in which the algorithm attempts to find the prime factors where num = 1000000. Your nested FOR loop will generate 1million operations before the next number is even considered!

Consider using the Sieve of Eratosthones to get all of the prime numbers up to a certain integer. It is not as efficient as certain other Sieves, but is easy to implement. Spend some time reading the theory behind the sieve before implementing--this will help your understanding of later problems.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: I agree that TheNuker needs to work on their algorithm, but trial division is adequate here - they don't really need to use a sieve.