# Why doesn't my answer to project euler 3 work?

Tags: python, primes

I've been trying to solve project Euler problem #3 for a while now. The code below still doesn't work the way I want it to.

> Question 3: The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

```
 getal = 13195
    x = 2 

    while x in xrange(2,getal):
        if getal % x == 0:
            num = getal / x
            for i in xrange (2,num):
                    if num % i == 0:
                        x += 1
                        break
                    else:
                        print num
        else:
            x += 1
            continue
```

As you can see I'm running it right now with 13195 for the sake of simplicity, but eventually it should have to work with the bigger number.

My output is this:

```
2639 2639 2639 2639 2639 1885 1885 1885 1015 1015 1015 455 455 455 377
377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 203 203 203 203 203 145 145
145 91 91 91 91 91 65 65 65 35 35 35 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29
29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29
```

29 goes on for a while longer than I showed.
I do understand it just prints the number as soon as it has found an "i" that this number cannot be divided by. But I don't know how to prevent it from doing this. Because in the end 29 is the right answer, however it should just give this answer once and right away.

Comment: Euler problems are great for learning to code! Glad you're having fun. Keep at it; persistence wins the day. As you learn to code, try to explain your algorithm using English. Then translate that to pseudocode and/or Python. When you explain your algorithm in human language, I think you'll decide it is not the correct algorithm.

Comment: as others have pointed out this is not the best way to do this - you should probably generate the primes upto the sqrt of the max number then find the largest that works

Comment: asked and answered many times on SO , e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279278/finding-largest-prime-number-out-of-600851475143) (nevermind the "Java" language tag, there's algorithmic discussion and a pseudocode in the answers).  --- or, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30039190/849891) has more detailed example.

Comment: Thanks for you answers! Actually I tried to come up with sort of an algorithm in english and translated it later to code. So right now that would be: select all the numbers that 'getal' can be divided by (start dividing by low numbers, to get the bigger 'num' first) subsequently check whether these numbers are primes. I get that this is not the most optimal code, but what would your suggestions be? I'd love to get some advice in order to improve my algorithms in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code to the code snippet below. It uses a list to store any candidates and then removes them if they are not prime numbers:

```
import math

getal = 600851475143
x = 2 
candidates = [];
while (x < int(math.sqrt(getal)+1)):    
    if getal % x == 0:                
        candidates.append(x)
        for i in xrange (2,int(math.sqrt(x)+1)):
             if x % i == 0:
                 candidates.remove(x)
                 break        
    x = x + 1
print str(candidates).strip('[]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `break` out of your `while` when you find the answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Au contraire. The question is "Why doesn't my answer to project euler 3 work?". In detail he states that his program goes into infinite loop at 29. This is because he is not breaking out of his while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not `incrementing 'x'` after `print num` statement.

```
  for i in xrange (2,num):
      if num % i == 0:
         break
      else:
         print num
  x += 1
```

you should be able to even getrid of second if statement as below

```
getal = 13195
x = 2 
while x in xrange(2,getal):
  if getal % x == 0:
      num = getal / x
      for i in xrange (2,num):
          if num % i == 0:
             break
          else:
             print num
  x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is 6857. You don't have to check from 2 to the number. Use the property of primes.Check only up-to the square root of the number that you are checking.You can use my Java Code for reference.

```
class p3{
public static boolean isprime(long y){
    double sq = Math.sqrt(y);
    long endl =(long) (sq+.5);
    for(long j = 2;j <=endl ;j++)
    {
        if(y%j==0){
        return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String []asd){
    long test = 600851475143L;
    long ans =-1;
    double e = Math.sqrt(test);
    long end = (long)(e+1);
    for(long i = 2 ; i <= end ;i++)
    {

        if(test%i==0){
            boolean val = isprime(i);
            if(val){
            ans = i;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
}
}
```

If you need any help. I have solved the problems in Project Euler and have saved them in my github repository. You are more than welcome to fork it.The url is:
https://github.com/vatsarahul999/ProjectEuler-.git

Writing the same code in python.

```
 def isprime(n):
   if n < 2:
     return False
  if n == 2: 
    return True    

  if not n & 1: 
    return False

   for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
      if n % x == 0:
        return False
   return True
```

Now the main program

```
v = 13195
x = 2
while(x*x <= v)
  if(isprime(x)):
       a = x
       while(v%x==0)
           v=v/x;
  x++
  print a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample (it can be improved in terms of performance):

```
import math

getal = 600851475143

def prime(number):
    for i in xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1):
        if (number % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True

def prime_factors(number):
    ret = []
    n = number
    primes = []
    for i in [item for item in xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1)]:
        if prime(i):
            primes.append(i)
    for i in primes:
        while n % i == 0:
            ret.append(i)
            n = n / i
    return ret

print prime_factors(getal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is everyone incrementing to find the largest number? Decrease!!!

```
def largestPrime(num):
  from __future__ import division
  for i in xrange(num//2 + 1, 1, -1):
    if num%i == 0 and all([i%j != 0 for j in range(2,i//2 + 1)]):
      return i
```

Answer (score -1):

you are over complicating, to get all factors

```
getal = 13195
for x in range(2, getal):
    if getal % x == 0:
        print x
```

this one should use the for loop not a while,
to use a while here it would be like this

```
getal = 13195
x = 2
while x < getal:
    if getal % x == 0:
        print x
    x += 1
```

you dont need to loop thru the constraints to do the work at the loop level - because you are doing it inside

Comment: This doesn't work: it prints all factors, but the problem is to print prime factors.

Comment: why the down vote - the answer was to help fix what  the questioner coded not to develop a full algorithm

Comment: Ah ... gotcha.  There are more problems with the algorithm; I'm part way through, but I think I'm going to drop it due to a fatal flaw in the original.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

you are actually very close to getting the right answer, you just need to remove indentation in your else statement to have a `for else` block:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> getal = 13195
>>> while x in range(2,getal):
        if getal % x == 0:
            num = getal // x
            for i in range (2,num):
                    if num % i == 0:
                        x += 1
                        break #this will break for loop
            else:#this is the only change, moving the else from an else inside of the for to a for else block
                    print (num)
                    break this will break while loop
        else: 
            x += 1
            continue


29
```

this is surprising for most people because the `for-else` statement is not well know but it pretty much means to only run the else block if the for block is not exited with a break.

With this in mind, YES, this code works but as a lot of other people said, this is NOT the best way to accomplish this task. Because @RahulVasta posted a good enough answer already, i wont. It is not to say that your logic does not work, but, since this is programming, there are infinite ways to approach a problem and some are better than others.

Comment: Please note that you will have to use `xrange` for `getal = 600851475143`

Comment: yes and i dont suggest doing that at all because it is just way too large of a number EDIT: this is python 3 where as original is python 2!

Comment: Suggesting using `for-else` seems like a recipe for confusing a novice programmer more than helping them.

Comment: if that is the reason for the downvote, i will have to disagree with you. yes, a `for-else` loop is not a structure that most novice programmers would ever need to use or should ever really use considering the odd syntax but it i do advise to find another way to do the job. the code works, albeit slowly, and the usage of the `for-else` loop is explained in an easy to understand manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.
I edited the answer of R Nar by changing range into xrange and it worked for 13195. However when i use 600851475143 it doesn't work. I'm running the program in Terminal on a macbook pro. I get that it's probably a tough calculation, even for a computer, but it should give a solution after a few seconds right? Does anyone know why it doesn't?